# Normality of $z$ transformation without preliminary assumption

Tags: pearson-r, fisher-transform, shapley-value

Assuming data $X_1,...,X_n, Y_1,...,Y_n$ we have Pearson correlation $r=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$. Fisher's $z$ transform is then $$z=0.5\log\left(\frac{1+r}{1-r}\right)=\tanh^{-1}(r)$$

If $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal and the pairs are i.i.d. then $z$ is approximately normally distributed. Thing is, bivariate normality is quite a serious preliminary assumption which I cannot commit to.

What happens if we violate this normality assumption? let's say $X,Y$ don't come from any *known* joint distribution but rather have some unknown distribution that can be found empirically. What can we say about the distribution of $z$ in such case?

---

Some background: My eventual target is measuring the agreement of two models regarding variable importance. For various reasons, my VI metric is global SHAP values. Given a dataset $X$ and two different models $M^A,M^B$, I can obtain the set of SHAP values for each model $\phi^A_j,\phi^B_j$ as the mean absolute magnitudes defined by [Lundberg et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-019-0138-9)). Then, I would like to assess the agreement level using the correlation coefficient either between $\phi^A,\phi^B$ vectors or some manipulation (e.g. order vector, quantization etc.). Sadly, no assumptions could be taken regarding bivariate normality of $\phi^A,\phi^B$ or any transformation.

Comment: 1. "... then z is normally distributed" -no, it isn't. Approximately normal, given some mild conditions. 2. "X,Y don't come from any joint distribution but rather have some unknown distribution" ... that the joint distribution is unknown doesn't mean they don't have one. 3. Are you really placing no  restrictions on the unknown joint population distribution? Is it not necessarily continuous, for example?

Comment: The components of $\phi$ vector (e.g. $\phi^A_j$ the SHAP value for variable $x_j$ under model $M^A$) are defined as the mean absolute magnitude of the SHAP values associated with this variable for $n$ training samples, $\phi_j^A=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left|\phi^A_{ij}\right|$. In addition, the pairs $(\phi^A,\phi^B_i)$ are not guaranteed to be i.i.d. If you have an idea regarding the possible continuity of such distribution when the $\phi^A_{ij}$ values come from (again) an unknown distribution, I'll be glad to hear.

Comment: If as you say they're not iid then presumably you're saying you don't have some basis for treating them as coming from some mixture distribution (since then presumably you can treat them as iid when the component is unknown).  If the model for the process that is selecting their values is nonprobabilistic, how are we talking about a distribution for z? Perhaps I'm being dense, I don't know.